# SQLite select stops working after 12 queries

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am unable to run though a list with URL:s and check their existence in my Sqlite database.
The first 12 queries works fine - then the request returns `none`.

Example:

```
import sqlite3

SQLITE_CONNECTION = sqlite3.connect('./data.db')

def main():
    url_list = ['url1', 'url2', ..., 'url99']
    for url in url_list:
        does_url_exist(url)


def does_url_exist(url):
    c = SQLITE_CONNECTION.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT url FROM raw_data WHERE url=?', (url,))
    result = c.fetchone()
    c.close()
    return result
```

I have checked the following things:

- The URL is in the database
- The URL:s encoding with `type(url)` - returns `str`
- Stripped whitespace with `url.strip()`

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Leading or trailing whitespace ?

Comment: No whitespace unfortunately.

Comment: What do you get if you run the query manually in sqlite?

Comment: When I run ```SELECT url FROM raw_data WHERE url= url99``` in DB Browser for Sqlite I get a hit. When I run it from my Python script - no hit.

Comment: When I run ```c.execute('SELECT url FROM raw_data') print(c.rowcount)``` I get -1. That seems weird. I would have thought I would get the all the rows (8k).

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it but I don't know the root of the problem.
Hopefully my method for debugging might be useful for someone.

I tried to query a different table and noticed that it wasn't available.
I connected to the DB using absolute path - I changed that to relative.

Problem solved.

I think I connected to the wrong database somehow. Or maybe some hidden backup of the database. I honestly don't know.